# Put two icons inside of an input field

Tags: html, css, uikit, semantic-ui

How do I put two icons inside an input element? Both icons should be clickable. I have installed both react-semantic-UI and uikit if it would be useful. Thank you.

[image: example]

Comment: Are you using fontawesome, icomoon or something else that transforms icons into fonts? If so, it's not too difficult and I can help you out

Comment: @SigurdMazanti thank you for your comment. I can use icomoon if it's not conflict with semantic or uikit. Do you know if icomoon can be used with them?

Comment: Hey again, I unfortunately don't know as I haven't used React myself. 
But from a couple Google searches I learned it should be feasible.

What you need to do is import the Icomoon icons into React, define Icomoon as a font, use that font in the `input`-element and then type the icon from Icomoon's own HTML or CSS-entity. Hope it makes sense and good luck :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to not put the icons in the input field, but style a container with a a prefix, the input and suffix. Remove all stylings from the input and then style the container like an input.

```
<div class="input">
  <span class="prefix"><i>YOUR ICON</i></span>
  <input />
  <span class="suffix"><i>YOUR ICON</i></span>
</div>

<style>
.input {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
}

input {
  all: unset;
}
</style>
```

Here is a small codepen I created:
https://codepen.io/webfussel/pen/rNYPzyX